# apt-get seems to not be installing a library package correctly

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, shared-library

Recently I have installed the library `liblz4.so` with `apt-get install liblz4-1`, but I have noticed that the above command only installs these files/links:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 -> liblz4.so.1.7.1
```

My understanding is that, in Ubuntu, the library names may contain the library version, but there must be always a link to one of these files that does not contain it, so `ld` and other binaries/libraries can find it. In the above example, such link would be `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so -> liblz4.so.1.7.1`. However, `apt-get` has not created this link, I have needed to create it myself.

Is this a 'failure' in the `liblz4` package or is it something expected in some Ubuntu packages? Is there any better way of installing it (that doesn't require to create the link manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Debian policy manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html), which governs this:

> When linking a binary or another shared library against a shared library, the SONAME for that shared library is not yet known. Instead, the shared library is found by looking for a file matching the library name with .so appended. This file exists on the file system as a symlink pointing to the shared library.
>
> Shared libraries are normally split into several binary packages. The SONAME symlink is installed by the runtime shared library package, and the bare .so symlink is installed in the development package since it’s only used when linking binaries or shared libraries.

So in the `liblz4-1` package, which contains the runtime library, you have `liblz4.so.1.7.1` which can be used by **already-compiled binaries** and in the development package `liblz4-dev` you have the `liblz4.so` symlink which allows the linker to embed the correct reference **when compiling them**.

The `liblz4-dev` package depends on the current version of the runtime package so that the symlink does not dangle, and they are updated together when the distribution releases updates to the library which require a change to the `SOVERSION`.

Comment: I tried to execute an already-compiled binary that uses `liblz4` and it failed because it didn't found the lib. I created the mentioned link and then it worked. How is the already-compiled binary supposed to find the lib if the bare .so symlink does not exist? Is it like a regex?

Comment: This is where `ld.so.conf` comes into play, and allows the dynamic resolver to locate the best matching library where more than one version is available (which is why libraries don't ship the bare name, which would break co-installation). Is the binary you have from an official Ubuntu package or an external source? That might explain it. Try running `ldd` on it and some other binaries and you'll see the difference.

Comment: In this example, the binary I have is built by me. I build lz4 and then link my binary against it. I was expecting to be able to exec. my bin. in any Ubuntu machine that has installed libz4, but the release package so to speak, not the devel one.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. If you don't have a **really** good reason to build `liblz` yourself (or anything else that the distro has already done for you), don't. It's the gateway to a world of pain.

Comment: I'm kind of forced to do that, my bin is built inside a much bigger project (with a very particular build system). Then, you mean that the right way to do this is to install the lz4-devel package and link against this lib., then the bin. will work in other machines that have this library installed (not the devel package, but the release one)?

Comment: `liblz4-dev`, yes. Bonus marks if you also package your program properly, and then the packaging helpers can build an automatic dependency on the runtime library package for your package and your users don't have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

According to `apt-file search liblz4.so`, the package that installs it is not the one you chose, but `liblz4-dev`:

```
$ apt-file search liblz4.so
liblz4-1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1
liblz4-1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
liblz4-1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
liblz4-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so
```

I have no idea what the difference is (if any) between `liblz4.so.1.7.1` and `liblz4.so`; this search was done on Mint 19.3 (bionic).